# A simple Query in flutter/firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I try to experience Firebase Live database with flutter. 
I just would like to get a value in the datasnapshot of the firebase response.

My Firebase

[image]

My Code

```
static Future<User> getUser(String userKey) async {
Completer<User> completer = new Completer<User>();

String accountKey = await Preferences.getAccountKey();

FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .reference()
    .child("accounts")
    .child(accountKey)
    .child("users")
    .childOrderBy("Group_id")
    .equals("54")
    .once()
    .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
  var user = new User.fromSnapShot(snapshot.key, snapshot.value);
  completer.complete(user);
});

return completer.future;
  }
}

class User {
  final String key;
  String firstName;

  Todo.fromJson(this.key, Map data) {
    firstname= data['Firstname'];
    if (firstname== null) {
      firstname= '';
    }
  }
}
```

I got Null value for firstname. 
I guess I should navigate to the child of snapshot.value. But impossible to manage with foreach, or Map(), ...

Kind regards, Jerome

Comment: I'm not familiar with flutter. But your database reference doesn't seem to match your database: you are using `.child("user")` but in your database it is `users`

Comment: And also `childOrderBy("Group_Id")` where there is `Group_id` in your db.

Comment: Ok thanks I corrected my post. But my real code is correct. In fact I got a response (JSON) if I use a print(snapshot.value) But I cannot get snapshot.value['firstName']

Comment: what object do you get as snapshot.value?

Answer (score 4):

You are querying with a query and the documentation for Queries ([here in JavaScript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events), but it is valid for all languages), says that "even when there is only a single match for the query, the snapshot is still a list; it just contains a single item. To access the item, you need to loop over the result."

I don't know exactly how you should loop, in Flutter/Dart, over the children of the snapshot but you should do something like the following (in JavaScript):

```
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
    var childData = childSnapshot.val();
    // ...
  });
```

and assuming that your query returns only one record ("one single match"), use the child snapshot when you do

```
var user = new User.fromSnapShot(childSnapshot.key, childSnapshot.value);
```

Comment: unfortunately foreach is not avaliable on DataSnapshot with flutter. I managed by casting my snapshot as Map. Thanks to all

Comment: Map.forEach((dynamic, dynamic) → void f) → void     
dart.core is available with Dart-Fluter

Answer (score 0):

This will give you Users in reusable dialog. There might be slight disservice to yourself if you don't use stream and stream-builders, the solution below is a one time fetch of the users' collection on FirebaseDB.

```
class User {
  String firstName, groupID, lastName, pictureURL, userID;

  User({this.firstName, this.groupID, this.lastName, this.pictureURL, this.userID});
  factory User.fromJSON(Map<dynamic, dynamic> user) => User(firstName: user["Firstname"], groupID: user["Group_id"], lastName: user["Lastname"], pictureURL: user["Picturelink"], userID: user["User_id"]);
}

Future<List<User>> users = Firestore.instance.collection("users").snapshots().asyncMap((users) {
  return users.documents.map((user) => User.fromJSON(user.data)).toList();
}).single;
```